# JAVASCRIPT remove parent key from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, flat

I have an array and i need to remove the top most 0 key, and leave the array with the following structure:

[array(24)]

0:{...}

1:{...}

2:{...}

3:{...}

until last key (24)

Right now this is how the array is:

[image]

I have tried many methods like assign, flat, array_shift, Object.keys(), Object.values(), and others without any luck.

Comment: what about [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)?

Comment: It gives me undefined when i log the resulting array.

Comment: please add the array and wanted result in text form.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The array with the objects seems to be inside another array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a designated function for it.
Try `myArray.shift()`

```js
const myArray = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}]
const firstElement = myArray.shift();
console.log(`first element: ${JSON.stringify(firstElement)}`)
console.log(`modified Array: ${JSON.stringify(myArray)}`)
```

Comment: It gives me undefined when i log the resulting array.

Comment: now it is working but the array remains with the parent key 0, it didn´t remove that key.

Comment: The shift method removes and returnes the first element of your array (all elements are beeing shifted to the left). So you just need to do <yourArray>.shift() and then examine the modifed array.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with an example so you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.values

```
myarray = {
    Array24 :
    {
        '0': { category :'saude'},
        '1': {price: '40'},
        '2': { category :'saude'},
        '3': {price: '40'},
        '4': { category :'saude'},
        '5': {price: '40'},
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(myarray));
```

You will get

```
  {
    '0': { category: 'saude' },
    '1': { price: '40' },
    '2': { category: 'saude' },
    '3': { price: '40' },
    '4': { category: 'saude' },
    '5': { price: '40' }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shift` method, like:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.shift();
console.log(arr);
```